# libGDX: smooth movement if justTouched

Tags: android, libgdx, textures

I want to check if the touchscreen is touched and move the position of my texture. With the check `input.isTouched()` it works well and i get a smooth movement of my texture while my touchscreen is touched.

```
public void update() {
   if(input.isTouched()){
      x += 60 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()
   }
}

public void render(SpriteBatch batch){
   batch.begin();
   batch.draw(texture, x, y); 
   batch.end();
}
```

Now I want to implement the movement of my texture when `input.justTouched()`. In this case my texture will move in only one frame when i'm doing `x += 600;`. My idea is a second render method in my render method, but i think that's not efficient and honestly i don't really know how it works.

Comment: Not sure I understand the issue, what are you trying to achieve? justTouched() is only called once, when you touch the screen, so x+=600 would only be called once. That's the point. Are you expecting it to be called repeatedly?

Comment: Yes, i want a smooth movement in for example 20 frames and not a movement in one frame with 600 units.

Comment: Likely several different ways to do it, depending on how your app is setup. Quick-hack could be to set a status/state for your texture when justTouched() and set a counter to 20. Then subsequent update() calls would increment the position and decrement 1 from your counter. Counter hits 0, stop repositioning. If you're using scened2d with actors, look into actions (like moveBy). Or other options "in between" those 2 extremes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){    // condition true when screen is currently touched.
    x += 60 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
}
```

So somehow we need to maintain condition/flag true for required number of frame to reach destination that is 600 in your case.

Having many possible solution to achieve this, and the simplest is :

```
public class GdxTest extends ApplicationAdapter {

   Texture texture;
   SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
   float x,y,endX;

   @Override
   public void create() {

      texture=new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
      spriteBatch=new SpriteBatch();
      y=20;
      x= endX=10;
   }

   @Override
   public void render() {

      Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
      Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

      spriteBatch.begin();
      spriteBatch.draw(texture,x,y);
      spriteBatch.end();

      if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){   // when new touch down event just occurred.           
        endX=600;  // give destination
      }

      if(x<endX){    // this condition will true unless x reaches endX or crossed
        x+=60 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void dispose() {
       texture.dispose();
       spriteBatch.dispose();
   }
}
```